# C++ template function that takes float or double

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to write a template function that will work on both `double` and `float`, something like that:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto someCalc(const T x) {
    return x * 4.0 + 3.0;
}
```

My issue is that both `4.0` and  `3.0` are doubles literal, thus I get the following error on clang:

```
error: implicit conversion increases floating-point precision: 'const float' to 'double' [-Werror,-Wdouble-promotion]
```

Is there an elegant way to write this code without having the up-conversion to double? The best I can come up with, is this

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto someCalc(const T x) {
    constexpr T four = 4.0;
    constexpr T three = 3.0;
    return x * four + three;
}
```

which I find less readable and harder to maintain for larger/more complicated function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto someCalc(const T x) {
    return x * T(4.0) + T(3.0);
}
```

Or with `static_cast`, if you prefer it.

Comment: I cannot use C-style cast and find `static_cast` to decrease readability in this numerical functions. What is the difference between this syntax `T(3.0)` and C-style casting `(T)3.0`

Comment: @JonathanDrolet In this case there is no difference. *"cannot use C-style cast"* Why not?

Comment: It's company policy, it has to compile with `-Wold-style-cast`. My first approach was to use C-style casting, which failed. I was surprise that your syntax worked.

Answer (score 2):

While HolyBlackCat's answer is completely viable, here's my two bits:

Your constants are supposed to mean something in that particular situation. They likely are magic numbers with some meaning. The best course of actions is to give them a name, if you want make them maintenable. And in newer C++ it allows them to be templates

```
#include <iostream>

namespace sdd // some_dirty_details 
{
/// @brief: Description of the constant
template <class T>
constexpr T some_constant  = static_cast<T>(3.0);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sdd::some_constant<float> << std::endl;
}
```